# Как реализовать задачу?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Нужно чтобы бралось случайное число от 0 до 100, и если оно больше чем предыдущее
( такое же от 0 до 100 ) оно выводилось зелёным, если наоборот - красным.

Примерный код:

```py
import random
from colorama import Fore
from time import sleep


while True:

    a = random.randint(0,100)

    sleep(0.5)

    if a > a:
        print(Fore.GREEN + str(a))
    elif a < a:
        print(Fore.RED + str(a))
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Так добавьте еще одну переменную, которая будет сохранять предыдущий результат и обновляйте ее после проверки уже.

Comment: @entithat, я просто не знаю как её обновлять после проверки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import random
from colorama import Fore
from time import sleep

colors = [Fore.RED, Fore.GREEN]

first = random.randint(0, 100)
while True:
    second = random.randint(0, 100)
    print(colors[second > first] + str(second))

    first = second
    sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random
from colorama import Fore
from time import sleep

a = random.randint(0, 100)

while True:

    b = random.randint(0,100)

    sleep(0.5)

    if b > a:
        print(Fore.GREEN + str(a))
    elif b < a:
        print(Fore.RED + str(a))

    a = b
```